# Why does it fail to open the referenced table if it already exists?

Tags: mysql

Somehow I can't create a join table for two entities I already have.

Here is what I run on MySQL just fine, the last one is the one I'm struggling with.

```
create table instructor_detail_table(
    instructor_detail_id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    instructor_class varchar(40) not null
);

create table instructor_table(
    instructor_id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    instructor_name varchar(40) not null,
    instructor_detail_id int not null,
    foreign key (instructor_detail_id) references instructor_detail_table (instructor_detail_id)
);

create table course_table(
    course_id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    course_class varchar(40) not null,
    instructor_id int not null,
    foreign key (instructor_id) references instructor_table (instructor_id)
);


create table student_table(
    student_id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    student_name varchar(40) not null,
    student_age int not null
);

create  table student_course_table(
    student_id int not null,
    course_id int not null,
    foreign key (student_id) references student_table (student_id),
    foreign key (course_id) references course_table (course_id),
    primary key (student_id, course_id)
);
```

When I try to create the student_course_table MySQL complaints it can't open the referenced table student_table

[image: error]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question? The code you showed looks fine.

Comment: I got the four first tables created and working but when trying to create the last one MySQL says ERROR 1824 (HY000): Failed to open the referenced table 'student_table'

Comment: Your code works fine in this db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7f8fe8eebb0bf047f7b64abce378ee02. The issue does not seem reproducible.

Comment: Bounce (reboot) your database server. This looks like something in your system leaked file descriptors or some other scarce resource. Don't sweat it unless it keeps happening.

Comment: Rebooting the server didn't work either. Tried a new database and worked just fine so I dropped the database to create it back. Probably not the best solution when it comes to some environments but this was for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can have this problem if the storage engine is not the good one.
For example 'MyISAM' instead of 'InnoDB' for the table 'student_table'.
Because MyISAM doesn't support foreign key.